# If statement for Users controller show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If trying to view my app as a unregistered user I get the error `` undefined method `letsgos' for nil:NilClass `` for the Users controller show action `@letsgo = current_user.letsgos.build`.

How can I add a if statement to that so unregistered users can view the show page?

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])    
    @question = Question.where('recipient_id = ? and answer is not null', params[:id]).page(params[:page]).per_page(3)
    @letsgo = current_user.letsgos.build    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render layout: 'new_application' }
      format.js { render partial: 'questions/questions', locals: {questions: @question} }
    end
  end
```

Comment: `@letsgo = current_user.letsgos.build if user_signed_in?`?

Comment: Or `@letsgo = current_user.letsgos.build unless current_user.blank?`  (I just like it when you directly examine the object that could potentially throw the error)

Comment: Thanks guys for the tip. Both setups are good, but I prefer how @JTG setup looks.

Comment: But @JTG setup is worse... better to use Devise provided helper.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel Why is it worse?

Comment: @JTG as I explained, you should use gem public API when possible. Not even mentioning that it's better to use normal than inverted login (if vs unless)

Comment: Except the entire point isn't to determine if a user is signed in, it's to insure that current_user isn't nil, and thus, the associated model can be built.  To use a circuitous API call when you can check the variable directly is...silly.  As for the inverted logic, that's pretty standard, don't know the logic behind thinking one way is "better" but, hey, to each his own.

Comment: `August`'s is better because it uses `Devise`' native functionality -- if the user isn't signed in, the `current_user` object will not be available